# How to return max date per month for user even if there is no duplication in some months

Tags: google-bigquery, partitioning

[Source Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ax8wX.png)

Above table is the source date; I highlighted the desired output

[MyQueryResult](https://i.stack.imgur.com/asnhT.png)

My query missing month 7/22, 8/22, 10/22, and 8/23.

below is my query. Please review it and let me know what I am missing and why some  months are not populating. thank you in advance!

#standardSQL
/* select PATIENT_ID,CAST(DATE(SOURCE_LAST_PROCESS_DTS) AS DATE) AS Modified Date
from (select PATIENT_ID,DOCUMENT_STATUS_TYPE_CD,SOURCE_LAST_PROCESS_DTS,
row number() over (partition by PATIENT_ID, extract(MONTH FROM SOURCE_LAST_PROCESS_DTS)
order by PATIENT_ID,SOURCE_LAST_PROCESS_DTS DESC) AS ROWNUM
from `T`)
WHERE ROWNUM = 1
and PATIENT_ID = '2636'--test
and DOCUMENT_STATUS_TYPE_CD ='1'--ACTIVE
and SOURCE_LAST_PROCESS_DTS is not null*/